# Is there a way to fit a machine learning model to MICE imputed datasets and pool the results?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-imputation, pooling, mice

I have a medical dataset that has a lot of missing values. I imputed five datasets using MICE in R. I want to fit a classification machine learning model to the dataset. I want to identify the most important variables using a feature selection method. Is it possible to fit a machine learning model to each dataset and identify the most important variables across all five datasets?

Or is there another suitable way to fit a machine learning model to a dataset with missing values?

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify which part is giving you trouble? The question is hard to understand, because on its face, the way to fit a model to each of the datasets is to fit a model to each. The way to pool the results is to choose a statistic of interest (perhaps the *mean* of the individual models) to summarize models' predictions.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I made some edits to the question. I can fit ML models to the each of the imputed datasets separately and obtain the most important variables. However, I don't know if there is a way to identify the most important variables across all the datasets.